# Question regarding Java's LinkedList class

Tags: java, linked-list

I have a question regarding the LinkedList class in Java.
I have a scenario wherein i need to add or set an index based on whether the index exists in the linkedlist or not. A pseudo-code of what i want to achieve is  --

```
if index a exists within the linkedlist ll 
     ll.set(a,"arbit")
else
      ll.add(a,"arbit")
```

I did go through the Javadocs for the LinkedList class but did not come across anything relevant.

Any ideas ?

Thanks
p1ng

Comment: Sounds like you want a java.util.Set instead of a LinkedList.

Comment: ... or perhaps a [Map](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)?

Comment: It's possible to have an indexed LinkedList, but the concept of a LinkedList makes indeces unnecessary.  If you need indeces you should be using something else.  Associative Arrays in Java are Maps, so I'll agree with Bart that a map is probably your best option here.

Comment: to help you research this more, you are looking for a `sparse array` implementation:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_array

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, but then i realized that a Hashmap implementation would help in many ways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about using a [Map](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) for this:

```
Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<Integer, String>();

// ...

int a = 5;

map.put(a, "arbit");
```

Even if `a` already exists, `put` will just replace the old String.

Answer (score 2):

Searching in linked list is not very efficient (O(n)). Have you considering using different data structure - e.g. HashMap which would give you O(1) access time?

Answer (score 2):

If you need sequential access as well as keyed access you might want to try a LinkedHashMap, available as from 1.4.2
http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html

Answer (score 1):

`Map<Integer, String>` is **definitely** a good (the best?) way to go here.

Here's an option for keeping with `LinkedList` if that's for some bizarre reason a requirement.  It has horrible runtime performance and disallows null, since null now becomes an indicator that an index isn't occupied.

```
String toInsert = "arbit";
int a = 5;

//grow the list to allow index a
while ( a >= ll.size() ) {
   ll.add(null);
}

//set index a to the new value
ll.set(a, toInsert);
```

If you're going to take this gross road, you might be better off with an `ArrayList`.

Why is it so bad?  Say you had only one element at index 100,000.  This implementation would require 100,000 entries in the list pointing to `null`.  This results in horrible runtime performance and memory usage.

Comment: You could allow `null` by using a special value to represent "unoccupied" (`private static final String EMPTY = new String();`).   But then you'd want to wrap your code into a class that encapsulates that, and honestly if you go that far you should really be using a more suitable data structure.

Answer (score 0):

LinkedList cannot have holes inside, so you can't have list `[1,2,3,4]` and then `ll.add(10,10)`, so I think there's something wrong with your example. Use either `Map` or search for some other sparse array

Comment: ArrayList can't have "holes" either.

Comment: @Mark Peters: Thanks, I forgot about it

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to use `a` as a key, and don't state whether you have items at index `i < a`. If you run your code when `ll.size() <= a` then you'll end up with a `NullPointerException`.

And if you add an item at index `a` the previous item at `a` will now be at `a+1`. 
In this case it would be best to remove item at `a` first (if it exists) then add item `"arbit"` into `a`. Of course, the condition above re: `ll.size() <=a` still applies here.

If the order of the results is important, a different approach could use a `HashMap&lt;Integer,String&gt;` to create your dataset, then extract the keys using `HashMap&lt;?,?&gt;.getKeySet()` then sort them in their natural order (they're numeric after all) then extract the values from the map while iterating over the keySet. Nasty, but does what you want... Or create your own OrderedMap class, that does the same...

Could you expand on why you need to use a LinkedList? Is ordering of the results important?